# Why is Adobe CQ 5.6.1 changing my JSON output?

Tags: jsp, servlets, aem

I have a bug on our site that seems to be related to how CQSE (the Servlet Engine running in Adobe AEM/CQ 5.6.1) outputs something in a JSP.

The use case is just using a .json.jsp to output a JSON object/hash, with some HTML fragments in the JSON values.

Here is an example of a JSP that gives me unexpected results:

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text");
%>
{"key":"<img src=\"/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i.j.40.40.png\">"}
```

What I get when I hit the URL on my localhost is:

```
{"key":"<img src="\">"}
```

Of course, I tested it in Tomcat to be sure its not some JSP spec thing, and got:

```
{"key":"<img src=\"/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i.j.40.40.png\">"}
```

1. What is happening?
2. What can I do to help provide better information for debugging help?  What I do know is that our Maven pom.xml's do not specify specific version numbers (which I think is...bad, right?) and so I imagine something has changed in the past 2 weeks (we know that this was working in production as late as January 8, 2015, but even if I use code from several months back, the issue reproduces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output is changed by the [Sling rewriter](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/output-rewriting-pipelines-org-apache-sling-rewriter.html) - you can confirm this by setting `/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/enabled` property to `false`. This rewriter parses all HTML pages produced by CQ. Your output is not a regular HTML, so probably there are some parse errors resulting in the invalid output.

Rewriter should affect only responses with content-type `text/html`, so changing it to `text` or even better `application/json` should fix it. Just use the `setContentType` method rather than `setHeader`:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Also, consider using [Sling servlet](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) bound to the component resource type and some JSON library (eg. [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) rather than JSP. You'll avoid redundant white spaces, escaping  issues and - last but not least - scriptlets.

Comment: Hi Tomek, thanks for the response.  Your response has definitely led me in the right direction -- I also had to disable another property as well, something someone else has installed called "Versioned ClientLibs", which is described at http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/versioned-clientlibs.html, and disabling the setting is described under "Rewriter Configuration Node".

Comment: BTW I would add that content type in my application is "application/json" and while my /lib/cq/config/rewriter/default has property contentTypes "text/html" as you stated, as does our Versioned ClientLibs...it still does the rewrite on this JSON, which is surprising.  Still investigating these details more.

Comment: Ah, so I totally mis-read your response, Tomek, about using setContentType vs setHeader -- I just noticed the difference between "application/json" and "text"!  The answer Tomek gave is 100% correct then.